# How to set value to a Reactive Form control in Angular6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

i want to set the value of the text box on click of some other button which is present outside the form, how can i do it

```
<form [formGroup]='student' (ngSubmit)='click()'>
<input type='text' formControlName='name'
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<input type='button' (click)='setValueOfTextbox()' value='some other button'>
```

now, when i click on this button and try to set the value, i am not able to do this

```
student:FormGroup

setValueOfTextbox(){
this.student.controls.name.setValue('foo')
}
```

how can i set the value of a button placed in the reactive form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value to form control in Reactive Forms in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275025/how-to-set-value-to-form-control-in-reactive-forms-in-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works just fine, please initialize your form group and the form controls

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.student = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl()
  })
}

setValueOfTextbox(){
  this.student.controls.name.setValue('foo')
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwcrcp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: well, the code was just a snippet of a bigger and complex code, how can i set a value of checkbox? is it the same way?

Comment: i added one checkbox control and tried this and it did not work,
   this.student.controls.gender.setValue('true');
could you please help on this?

Comment: please see my updated stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-biwuvy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @LijinDurairaj: It will work the same, in your stackblitz example you haven't created a formControl for gender: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6eelg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts