# Angular - Send Form Data on Form Submit with updated form values

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form with an action url

```
<form 
  ngNoForm 
  id="login-form" 
  [formGroup]="loginForm" 
  (submit)="onSubmit()" 
  [action]='actionUrl' 
  method='POST'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-input" for="email">username</label>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      formControlName="username" 
      name="username" 
      id="username" 
      [ngModel]="username" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-input" for="password">Password</label>
    <input 
      [type]="password" 
      formControlName="password" 
      name="password" 
      class="form-control" />
  </div>
</form>
```

in my component.ts i have this:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.username = 'updatedusername';
  this.testFormElement.nativeElement.submit();
}
```

I want to send to action url the `updateusername` and always send the value entered in ui.

How can I send the new value for and username input? I need to add additional values to username that user has been entered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set value to form control in Reactive Forms in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275025/how-to-set-value-to-form-control-in-reactive-forms-in-angular)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your template code, you're already using the `ReactiveFormsModule`.

You can get the value of the form using `this.loginForm.value`

Send your API call on the `onSubmit` method using `HttpClient`, like this:

```
onSubmit() {
  this.http.post('your-api-url-here', this.loginForm.value)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2npmwz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.