# How can i safely assign a value to a control in Angular Reactive

Tags: angular

I have a Observable that returns Data from an API. In this case there are 3 type of Addresses which could be returned, Office, Mailing and Home. But in the case user did not provide a Home Address that element does not exist in the API response.

i use

```
setInitialValue() {
this.userForm.setValue( {
  home_address_city = this.userProfile.home_address.city
})
}
```

this works fine as long as that element exists. So i am wondering what is the safest way to handle this in case that this.userProfile.home_address.city does not exist

Comment: Why not add a null check? `home_address_city = this.userProfile.home_address.city ?  this.userProfile.home_address.city: 'No address'`.  And if the property does not exists in the response, `undefined` will be set, which is still ok because its not an error.

Comment: a slight corection to Amit's response. home_address_city = this.userProfile.home_address? this.userProfile.home_address.city: 'No address'
the previous response sill assumed the userprofile always had a home address. and if doesn't, you would get an error.

Comment: @Edward Yeah perfect. Thanks! TBH, I did not notice the `city` property. I thought `home_address.city` was all a single prop under `userProfile`.

Comment: yes i just tried Amit's answer and as long as there is a home_address: {} in the response it works fine but as soon as its missing i get the error "Can not Read Property.  So how would i correctly check for null on home_address as well as city. I assume checking this.userProfile.home_address? will only check if home_address exist not the city element underneath

Comment: @NoSoup4You `home_address_city = this.userProfile.home_address ? this.userProfile.home_address.city : ''`;
this will only try to get the "city" property if home_address is defined. if you need to also check if "userProfile" exists, then you can do `home_address_city = (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address) ? this.userProfile.home_address.city : ''`

Answer (score 0):

If your project has TypeScript 3.7 installed, you can make use of [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

```
setInitialValue() {
  this.userForm.setValue({
    home_address_city: this.userProfile?.home_address?.city
  })
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to chain the checking of the properties within the if statement to check for `home_address` and `city`:

```
 setInitialValue() {
  if (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address && this.userProfile.home_address.city) {
    this.userForm.setValue({
      home_address_city: this.userProfile.home_address.city
    });
  }
}
```

I would like to note that your syntax for setValue is wrong, you should replace the `=` with `:`.

**EDIT**

Following up on your comment, you can try this:

```
setInitialValue() {
  this.userForm.setValue({
    home_address_city: (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address && this.userProfile.home_address.city) ? this.userProfile.home_address.city : '',
    home_address_zip: (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address && this.userProfile.home_address.zip) ? this.userProfile.home_address.zip : '',
  });
}
```

Comment: Typescript 3.7 is not compatible with Angular.

Comment: @MaihanNijat Actually, you can install it, but it is not officially supported by Angular. I have explained it over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216166/10959940

Comment: Okay. In null case, would it assign undefined or would not assign anything at all?

Comment: @MaihanNijat it would assign undefined.

Comment: Ok if i modify your code to setInitialValue() {
  if (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address && this.userProfile.home_address) {
    this.userForm.setValue({
      home_address_city: this.userProfile.home_address.city ? this.userProfile.home_address.city : '',
      home_address_zip: this.userProfile.home_address.zip ? this.userProfile.home_address.zip : '',
    });
  }
}i run into the issue that i can not use it to setValue for othe controls and check them as setValue requires me to provide values for all controles

Comment: @NoSoup4you in that case, you can use patchValue instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275025/how-to-set-value-to-form-control-in-reactive-forms-in-angular/55275042#55275042)

Comment: iknow but i was wondering if there was a way to move the  if (this.userProfile && this.userProfile.home_address ) inside the setValue part but i guess that is not an option

Comment: But what happens in the case that this.userProfile.home_address does not exist ? arent we then back to the issue from before ?

Comment: @NoSoup4you sorry I misread your code. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
setInitialValue() {
    this.userForm.setValue(this.userProfile.home_address.city || '')
}
```