# How to set a form control value in angular reactive form from other field values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular reactive form and need to set the value of a `Full Name` form control by using the values of `First Name` and `Last Name`. I have the code as follows :

```
<form [formGroup]="personForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" formControlName="full_name" maxlength="255">
</form>
```

and the form is defined as :

```
this.personForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    first_name: [_.get(person, 'first_name', ''),Validators.required],
    last_name: [_.get(person, 'last_name', ''),Validators.required],
    full_name: [_.get(person, 'display_name', ''),Validators.required]
 });
```

I would like to generate the `full_name` value as the combination of `first_name` and `last_name`when clicking on the `full_name` input field. How can this be possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set value to form control in Reactive Forms in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275025/how-to-set-value-to-form-control-in-reactive-forms-in-angular)

Comment: But how can I generate the combined value of change or on focus ?

Comment: you can use `blur` output event. Add `(blur)="function"` on both the input box and concat the values into the `function`. https://angular.io/guide/user-input#on-blur

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form [formGroup]="personForm">
    <input #input1 type="text" formControlName="first_name" maxlength="255">
    <input #input2 type="text" formControlName="last_name" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" formControlName="full_name" maxlength="255" value="{{input1.value}} {{input2.value}}">
</form>
```

Comment: Will this approach update the value into `full_name` variable as well?

Comment: Yes, but if this is insert form You no need show a user this data on submit form join value to fullname in code behind and save it in data base, next when You want to show in this meaner only get one value from db and show it in some field or label, i think

Answer (score 0):

what do you think can this help you?

Demo: https://angular-formgroup-vsdjkc.stackblitz.io

In the example, I use the formGroup valueChanges to listen all of the form changes.

And just do the patchValue with the updated first name and last name

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with `blur` and `patchValue`. Please check the below demo link.

`blur` - On focus change it will call function, concate the `first_name` and `last_name` value stores into `full_name`.

`patchValue` - it will update value into `full_name` and displays into form.

[blur demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ehw5j)