# Angular how to set radio button checked in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, forms

I am building a very simple form like this:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    choose: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  })
```

I know that I can set my radio button to checked like this:

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    choose: new FormControl('1', Validators.required)
  })
```

My question is how to set radio button later. Maybe in ngOnInit()? Background is that I first do some API calls in init and after this I want to choose which radio button should be checked and which not. I don't want to do it in Template. Or is this only way?

Comment: Check this:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the **setValue()** method after the API calls like this:

```
this.form.controls.choose.setValue('1');
```

Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275025/how-to-set-value-to-form-control-in-reactive-forms-in-angular) a read for a detailed answer regarding how to set the value to form control in Reactive Forms in Angular. Happy coding :)